# SQLite header and source version mismatch OSX 10.10

Tags: macos, sqlite

When I am trying to use SQLite3 from my machine I am getting the following error:

`./sqlite3
SQLite header and source version mismatch
2014-08-15 22:37:57 c8ade949d4a2eb3bba4702a4a0e17b405e9b6ace
2011-11-01 00:52:41 c7c6050ef060877ebe77b41d959e9df13f8c9b5e`

Can you pls tell me how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: I ran into this and this post helped:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/443379/sqlite-header-and-source-version-mismatch

Comment: Thanks, but the location they are specifying are for UNIX machine...any idea for the same locations on OSX?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a mismatch between the linker file created by SQLite. Was able to resolve this using the dynamic compiling.

Thanks for responding.